# Codeigniter 4 doesn't locate default controller in subdirectory with underscore for hyphenated url

Tags: php, routes, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-4

I have an [earlier post on the Codeigniter forum](https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-78215.html) relating to this where I am trying to support URLs with dashes in them. Long story short, I must use dashes in my controller subdirectory names if I want to have dashes in my url. For whatever reason, the CI4 auto-routing is unable to recognize when a url with a dash in the path is referring to a controller subdirectory with an underscore.

E.g., if I want this url to connect to the default **Home** controller in my **Nested-directory** subdirectory:

`https://www.example.com/subdir/nested-directory`

Then I have to use a dash in the file system directory name. That url works if I put my controller in this location:

`app/Controllers/Subdir/Nested-directory/Home.php`

*Note* that the properly working Home controller uses an underscore in its namespace:

```php
namespace App\Controllers\Subdir\Nested_directory;

use App\Controllers\BaseController;

class Home extends BaseController {

    public function index()
    {
        die("this is " . __METHOD__);
    }
}
```

That same url does *not* work if I put it in a directory with an underscore:

`app/Controllers/Subdir/Nested_directory/Home.php`

Curiously, it the dash in the url I request `does` get properly routed to an underscore while CI4 is calculating the controller path. *However*, CI4 doesn't bother to check if the url is requesting the default Home controller in a subdirectory. The complaint it gives is:

> Controller or its method is not found: \App\Controllers\Subdir\Nested_directory::index

So it *almost* works, is just doesn't bother checking for the default **Home** controller in a subdir.  Additionally, if I change my url to have an underscore in it, then CI4 can locate the Home controller in the subdirectory named with an underscore. This url:

`https://www.example.com/subdir/nested_directory`

Connects correctly to the controller here:

`app/Controllers/Subdir/Nested_directory/Home.php`

Previously, it was enough to simply make sure I name my subdirectories with dashes so they match the urls, however **this does not work when i must add a $routes->add directive mapping urls to a controller that happens to live in a subdirectory with a dash.** This route directive works just fine in my Config/Routes file if **Nested_directory** contains an underscore:

```php
$routes->add("foobar/([0-9]+)", "Subdir\Nested_directory\Home::index/$1");
```

This serves a request for https://www.example.com/foobar/123 with the correct Home controller.

But if if the **Nested-directory** subdirectory containing my Home controller contains a dash, meaning my Home controller file is

`app/Controllers/Subdir/Nested-directory/Home.php`

then this will not work:

```php
$routes->add("foobar/([0-9]+)", "Subdir\Nested_directory\Home::index/$1");
```

This will also not work:

```php
$routes->add("foobar/([0-9]+)", "Subdir\Nested-directory\Home::index/$1");
```

Please note that I need to have these dashes instead of underscores because that is [recommended by Google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/url-structure). I also very much do not want to create a big, complicated Routes file where I must route all of my many controllers. The auto-routing of CI3 was working just fine. I think this problem could be remedied with a small code change.

Can anyone point me to a solution?

For reference, here is my Config/Routes.php file

```php
// Create a new instance of our RouteCollection class.
$routes = Services::routes();

// Load the system's routing file first, so that the app and ENVIRONMENT
// can override as needed.
if (file_exists(SYSTEMPATH . 'Config/Routes.php'))
{
 require SYSTEMPATH . 'Config/Routes.php';
}

/**
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Router Setup
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
$routes->setDefaultNamespace('App\Controllers');
$routes->setDefaultController('Home');
$routes->setDefaultMethod('index');
$routes->setTranslateURIDashes(true);
$routes->set404Override();
$routes->setAutoRoute(true);

/**
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Route Definitions
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

// We get a performance increase by specifying the default
// route since we don't have to scan directories.
$routes->get('/', 'Home::index');

// neither of these work if the controller is in Nested-directory
//$routes->add("foobar/([0-9]+)", "Subdir\Nested-directory\Home::index/$1");
$routes->add("foobar/([0-9]+)", "Subdir\Nested_directory\Home::index/$1");
```

Comment: You've made a fair case on their github as to why this is a bug, I would give that some time to play out. Otherwise, as you've seemingly already identified the problem, you can alter system files with the understanding that they can/will be overwritten if/when you update the framework again.

Comment: @parttimeturtle thanks for chiming in. I have submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/pull/4307) which I believe fixes the problem. Any attention or input there would be most welcome.